# using function before return

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Hi I'm reviewing one sample in react redux and in action file I'm seeing this function

```
function login(email, password) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request({ email }));

        userService.login(email, password)
            .then(
                data => {
                    dispatch(success(data.user));
                    history.push('/');
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
                }
            );
    };

    function request(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user } }
    function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error } }
}
```

it's clear that this function is returning dispatch file to call reducer 
the only part I don't understand it correctly is how it's defines some functions after return and using it in the return. 
this function is working properly but if I can do something to make it better please tell me.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks! I couldn't find that duplicate

Answer (score -1):

Although functions are declared after they are used, it is still legal as `function`s (not arrow functions) and `var` (not `let` or `const`) are hoisted to the beginning of the block so the code is effectively.

```
function login(email, password) {
    function request(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user } }
    function success(user) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user } }
    function failure(error) { return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error } }

    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(request({ email }));

        userService.login(email, password)
            .then(
                data => {
                    dispatch(success(data.user));
                    history.push('/');
                },
                error => {
                    dispatch(failure(error));
                    dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
                }
            );
    };
}
```

MDN has an [article of hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: Anybody want to say why they down-voted?

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, it does not matter where you **declare** a variable or a function. In the end, it is as if it was declared at the beginning of the current scope.

Look at this:

```js
log("hello");

function log(greeting) { console.log("hello"); }

//
```

It is, in fact, as if you'd defined `log` at the beginning.

The same happens with var, but with a difference:

If you have:

```
console.log(a); // Exception. `a` is unknown.
```

However, if you declare `a` afterwards

```js
console.log(a); // writes undefined

var a = 2;
```

Why does it write `undefined`? You'll see that we no longer get an exception. That's because the declaration was moved, but not the assignment. The above code is in fact equivalent to:

```js
var a;

console.log(a);

a = 2;
```